# count the total time of values in textbox. i want to calculate the time of the value

Tags: c#, timespan

i have some value in text box . i want to calculate the time of that value in text box .means for how long that value is there in the text box.

values are of Boolean type . it can be 1 or 0 .i want to calculate the time span of each value also their differences .

Comment: Good that you want to do that. What have you done so far?

Comment: nothing bro thats why i am here .thats the last thing remaning .task given to me

Comment: people tend to non-reactions and downvotes when a question is posted without any visible own efforts to tackle the issue and when questions are phrased with "I want" or "I need".

Comment: i need to calculate the duration for how long value was 1 or 0 ..kindly help me

Comment: how does this value get into your textbox? do you know the time of it's appearance?

Comment: i can post my code here but that is out of the context. i have one text box .. using onditions to check if condition is true value will be 1 if not 0 . i just want to know for how long it was 0 or 1 . duration

Comment: try
        //            {
        //                var query = "select 1";


        //                var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

        //                connection.Open();
        //                /

                       

        //                command.ExecuteScalar();
                        
        //               ** sqlserver_status.Text = "Active";**
                       
        //                rectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(2, 245, 156));
        //

Comment: here i want to check the duration of  sqlserver_status.Text="Active".. for how long it was active and for how long it values changes to something else

Comment: thats my first time thats why i can not properly convey my message .

Comment: no problem. I had also my first post here :) there is an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38721535/edit) button below your post, you can use it and add the code to your existing post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not much code that you posted, but I would give it a try.
I don't see in your code any `bool` variable.
You probably should have one where you would save the current state.

since you write the value into the `TextBox` you could start the timer that MMbach suggested right after the line:

```
sqlserver_status.Text = "Active";
// start timer here
```

whenever further in you code this status changes, you would stop the timer and check the elapsed time.

You could also use the [StopWatch](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiorebTgqPOAhWElCwKHaagBOsQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fde-de%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.diagnostics.stopwatch(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNGfa3QBD71Ez1Xo9y4V3yuW9XgEWw&cad=rja) class for that.
It has a property called `Elapsed` which :

> Gets the total elapsed time measured by the current instance.

If you need to run it in the background I would advise to go for the `Timer`.

Below is a small Demo realised with a `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`.
There are many more realisation to this problem. It always depends on the structure of your program which realisation is better or worse.

This is a small Console application where you decide **when** to change the `State` Variable. It will monitor your decision process.

```
public class TimeDemo
{
    // Property to catch the timespan
    public TimeSpan TimeOfState { get; set; }

    // Full Property for the state
    private bool state;

    public bool State
    {
        get { return state; }
        set
        {
            // whenever a new state value is set start measuring
            state = value;
            this.TimeOfState = StopTime();
        }
    }
    // Use this to stop the time
    public System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch StopWatch { get; set; }

    public TimeDemo()
    {
        this.StopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    }
    //Method to measure the elapsed time
    public TimeSpan StopTime()
    {
        TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);

        if (this.StopWatch.IsRunning)
        {
            this.StopWatch.Stop();
            t = this.StopWatch.Elapsed;
            this.StopWatch.Restart();
            return t;
        }
        else
        {
            this.StopWatch.Start();
            return t;
        }
    }

    public void Demo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please press Enter whenever you want..");
        Console.ReadKey();
        this.State = !this.State;

        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Time: " + TimeOfState.ToString());


        Console.WriteLine("Please press Enter whenever you want..");
        Console.ReadKey();
        this.State = !this.State;

        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Time: " + TimeOfState.ToString());



        Console.WriteLine("Please press Enter whenever you want..");
        Console.ReadKey();
        this.State = !this.State;

        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Time: " + TimeOfState.ToString());


    }
}
```

May be you can adjust it according to your case.

Comment: can you provide me a demo please